# No module named 'django.templates'

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, pycharm

I am using python 3.4, django 1.8. I am using pycharm for developing. While running the program ,I am getting 'No module named 'django.templates'' error.

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for dj project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.1.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'uhqkhi7h_w48bz*gnr+_!roaa8@c_)087a(!ees)mn2=n=lv-r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'dj.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.templates.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.templates.context_processors.debug',
                'django.templates.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.load_template_source',
)
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'dj.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates'),
)
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', views.post_list),
]
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dj.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

post_list.html

```
<html>
<body>
<p>
    hihiiii
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

dj/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Error

```
ImportError at /
No module named 'django.templates'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 1.8.1
Exception Type: ImportError
Exception Value:    
No module named 'django.templates'
Exception Location: C:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py in import_module, line 109
Python Executable:  C:\Python34\python.exe
Python Version: 3.4.1
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\ankur anand\\PycharmProjects\\dj',
 'C:\\Users\\ankur anand\\PycharmProjects\\dj',
 'C:\\Windows\\SYSTEM32\\python34.zip',
 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib',
 'C:\\Python34',
 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Fri, 15 May 2015 18:08:59 +0530
```

Answer (score 27):

This can happen if you are not familiar with Pycharm IDE refactoring.

- You renamed the "templates" directory to another name by refactoring.
- When you do this, Pycharm also renames some strings in "settings.py".

**Solution:** Right click your "setting.py":

- `LocalHistory -> ShowHistory` then restore you "setting.py".

Answer (score 10):

Use this and replace it existing values. As in last post he told you that you just needed to remove "s" from relevant fields. But if you couldn't understand it then just copy paste.

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],

        },
    },
]
```

Answer (score 6):

As the error mentions, there's no such thing as `django.templates`.

However, there *is* a `django.template`. You'll want to remove the `s` from all of the relevant lines that refer to `templates`.

While you're at it, you should also move your `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` to their proper location (within the `TEMPLATES` setting).

Read more [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/#the-templates-settings).

Answer (score 2):

This did happened due to Refactoring in Pycharm. I faced the same issue initially, when changed the directory name "template" to "templates".
To resolve this: Right click settings.py > local history > show history > revert.
It reverted the changes made in the settings file due to refactoring but kept the directory name to "Templates". Hence, resolving the issue.

Comment: man you saved me hours of stress..... thank you!
i did the same thing with pycharm and it renamed everything in settings and my dev settings to templates.......lol

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exception with you when start my first django project...
i think maybe you changed the template dir name from 'template' to 'templates' in pycharm ,but didn't aware that pycharm changed the TEMPLATES.context_processors configs in setting.py at the sametime. it changed

```
django.template.context_processors.debug 
django.template.context_processors.request
```

to

```
django.templates.context_processors.debug 
django.templates.context_processors.request
```

.it's the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in settings.py templates list is having key name DIRS that is empty, it should not be **'DIRS':[]**, RIGHT WAY -> add that value **'DIRS':[BASE_DIR / 'templates']** in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

True, it is related to refactoring directory name from template to templates in my case.Need to correct change settings.py file under TEMPLATES(for me error was no module found "django.template" )
changes to be made under TEMPLATES is remove "s" from

```
django.templates.context_processors.debug

django.templates.context_processors.request
```

to:

```
django.template.context_processors.debug

django.template.context_processors.request
```