# Module Not Found Error after moving directory and back

Tags: django, module, directory

After moving my directory back and forth, I am recieving the below error. Not sure how to resolve this.

The files are currently sitting in the directory they originated from. What seettings should I be looking at when I get an error like this.

```
C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\PyCharm-P\ch-0\192.6817.19\bin\runnerw64.exe C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Nathan/PycharmProjects/DJANGO_TemplateApp/manage.py runserver 8000
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
        self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
        super().execute(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
        output = self.handle(*args, **options)
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 67, in handle
        if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
        self._setup(name)
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
        self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\PycharmProjects\DJANGO_TemplateApp\venv\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
        mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
      File "C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
        return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'DJANGO_TemplateApp'
```

Comment: Can you post your settings.py here?

Comment: This might help [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30260055/no-module-named-django-templates)

Comment: https://a.uguu.se/QaCMGzqMryUV_settings.py

Comment: That is the settings.py used

Comment: What is the name of your Template directory?

Comment: The template directory is "templates". The app directory sits under "DJANGO_TemplateApp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this all happened because you moved your virtualenv and i think the good way to solve this is to create a new virtualenv and copy your project to it and install the requirements

Comment: I just moved all code into a new project, installed required dependencies and it worked. Not sure what happened here. Thanks!

Comment: when you create a virtualenv this virtualenv settings contains the virtualenvc path and when you move it it will not work and there is some packages that enable you to move the virtualenv to a new path ^_^

Comment: Good ^_^ , happy coding and do not forget to check my answer as useful and as the best answer